# Tensorflow: How can I run my testing set on a trained Neural Net

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, neural-network

I have created a Neural Net that takes as input an RGB corrupted image and produces a clean version of it. After I finish training my NN I want to test it on a big set of 50 images. Each input (image) consists of a batch sized 64*32*32*3( I crop my image in 64 patches and then feed it to the NN). I train my NN with the following code:

```
# placeholders, variables etc here
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

#loading data to queue
training_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(clean_set, shuffle=False)
cor_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(corrupted_set, shuffle=False)

reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
key, value = reader.read(training_queue)
cor_key, cor_value = reader.read(cor_queue)

data = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels = 3)
cor_data = tf.image.decode_jpeg(cor_value, channels = 3)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

for i in range (64):

    my_data = sess.run([key,data,cor_key,cor_data])
    im_list.append(my_data[1].reshape(1,-1))
    key_list.append(my_data[0])
    cor_im_list.append(my_data[3].reshape(1,-1))
    cor_key_list.append(my_data[2])

for j in range(my_times):
        _, y =  sess.run([train_step,h_y],feed_dict={x: cor_im_list, y_: im_list})


print 'finished training NN'
coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
```

This works fine!

Now I want to test my data set:

```
ressu = []
test_im_list = []
test_key_list = []

# I have 50 images in 50 folders (each folder contains the 64 patches of the image)
for i in range(50):

    path = 'randomize_text/permutated_data/perm_test_'  + str(i) + '/*.jpg'
    testing_set =  glob.glob(path)
    testing_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(testing_set, shuffle=False)

    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()

    test_key, test_value = reader.read(testing_queue)

    test_data = tf.image.decode_jpeg(test_value, channels = 3)

    for j in range (64):
        print j
        my_data = sess.run([test_key,test_data])
        test_im_list.append(my_data[1].reshape(1,-1))
        test_key_list.append(my_data[0])

    psi =  sess.run(y,feed_dict={x: test_im_list})
    ressu.append(psi)
```

If put this code right after finishing training the NN the program becomes unresponsive and my guess is that I dont use the coord and threads so I cant handle the big set (even if place it right before I close threads). If I load it the way I loaded my training set I can only do it for one image which is not enough, I need to load them all.

How can I test my trained NN with my testing set?

Thanks